# Conversions between object types between application boundaries

Tags: design, architecture, programming-practices, web-applications, domain-driven-design

**Disclaimer:**
The post is `Spring` and `Hibernate` specific but any generic advice would be helpful too.

I recently started on a project which contains following technology stack `Hibernate`, `Spring MVC` and `Angular2`.

After reading a bunch of blogs and tutorials I found clean architecture has a good set of guidelines and I learned few key concepts:

1. Domain logic should be independent of the implementation details.
2. Dependencies should point inwards.
3. Data crossing boundaries should be plain data structures.

I also googles some key concepts:

1. DAO, objects which communicates with database(not sure I got this 100%).
2. DTO, objects which crosses application boundaries something like `JSON`?

In spring we have this concept of `JPA annotation` and the entities which are supposed to be heart of business logic serves as `DAO` too if I am not mistaken.

Taking example of a hypothetical application `Imagica` the user can upload an image, add tags and comments to it. The server side contains a controller to handle `REST` requests.

So, taking a couple of scenarios here:

**Upload Image**

User uploads an `Image` with some tags. The Front End does some data conversion and my controller gets the data in following format:

```
{
  id: null,
  caption: string,
  data: <base64 encoded>,
  tags: List<id>
}
```

**Question 1:** can I say it as `DTO`?

Spring does some auto conversion somehow and get a new object created from the given JSON data as method parameter (I think it uses some library called `Jackson`), I created a class for it named it
`ImageResource`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method=POST)
public void add(ImageResource resource) { ... }
```

**Question 2:** `ImageResource` is also a `DTO`?

The `ImageController` is a simple controller which passes this `ImageResource` to the `ImageService` as it is. The `ImageService` depends on `ImageEntity` and couple `Repositories` for saving images and `Tags`, I chose to return nothing on successful save(maybe returning a new ID is a good idea).

**Question 3:** Is `ImageEntity` acting as `DAO` here?

**Getting all image data**

Skipping all irrelevant details and hoping it well understood.

**Question 4:** The `ImageService` returns `ImageListResource` and the conversion is done by the service itself. I have seen some examples where the service returns entities but I am not sure if that is a right strategy.
Coming back to question, whose responsibility it is to convert to `ImageListResource`, controller or service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: can I say it as DTO?

This is not an object, just serialized data that comes from the user input through a web request.

> Question 2: ImageResource is also a DTO?

I'm not familiar with Spring, but from your explanation it seems to me that this is just some helper feature deserializes the input from Question 1 into a custom class defined by you. So, this ImageResource is just a reflex from the information from question 1, which are just basic input from the user; this is still not your domain models.

When you convert this into a ImageEntity and pass it to your service, then this is a DTO, crossing the boundary from the Web app and your core application.

> Question 3: Is ImageEntity acting as DAO here?

I think the Repositories you mentioned act as the DAO (data access object), since they do the job of persistence and retrieving necessary info from DB.

> Question 4: ... whose responsibility it is to convert to ImageListResource, controller or service?

If the service you mentioned is part of your core application, then it should not perform the conversion; it must be done by some specific part of your client. In this case, I think it's fine for the controller to convert the data in some format appropriate for the client.